# regex month replacement MM-DD-YYYY to 'month_string DD, YYYY'

Tags: python, regex, csv, date

I'm working in python:

I'm trying to convert a column in a csv file with out using excel, just regex.

```
month_dictionary={"January":1,
"February":2, 
"March":3, 
#...etc
```

this is what I have so far.

```
with open(file, newline="") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        for item in row:
            item.replace(r"(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/gm", month_dictionary[r"${1}"], r"${2}, ${3}")
```

I don't know regex that well, and I am having some trouble googling this.

the error I get is:

```
KeyError: '${1}'
```

so How do I properly format that replace regex to do what I want?

```
05-25-1999
into
May 25, 19999
```

I'm hoping this is an easy question related to my ignorance in formatting.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason you are not using ISO 8601 format?

Comment: `str.replace()` doesn't process regular expressions, you need to use `re.sub()`. And the solution is to use a function as the replacement, it can do the dictionary lookup.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Chill out man, OP is just trying to give full context. I don't think this question deserves a downvote.

Comment: But why do this with a regular expression instead of the `datetime` library?

Comment: @JamesGeddes full context is not helpful when it interferes with the reproducibility of a MRE.

Comment: When you create a [mre], you should remove as much irrelevant code as you can. In this case, reading from a file has nothing to do with the regex, and your MRE could have been  much more minimal and reproducible if it was condensed down to: `item = "05-25-1999"; item.replace(...)`

Comment: @altruios Why do you need to use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James has already added an [answer](/a/68820563) using python's inbuilt `datetime` module, but if you still want to use regex (for example if this is an exercise to learn regex), here are some things that went wrong with your approach:

1. Your regex doesn't match your input string: You're trying to match a hyphen-separated date, your regex is forward-slash-separated. You need `r"(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})"`.
2. In python, regex matching groups are referenced using `\1`, `\2`, etc, not `${1}`, `${2}`.
3. You need to use `re.sub()` to replace with regex, not `str.replace()`.
4. Your `month_dictionary` is backwards. You need to look up using the *month number*, not the month name, so your dictionary's keys need to be the month number. If you already have `month_dictionary` and don't want to manually write out the reverse, you can do it with a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
month_num_dict = {num: name for name, num in month_dictionary.items()}
```

5. You can't look up from a dictionary while doing `re.sub()`. The replacement string must be something that the regex engine can understand, so it can only be a constant string or a string that uses the groups, or a function that takes a `match` object. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Now, let's use the ability of `re.sub()` to take a *function* that returns the replacement string.

```
item = '05-25-1999'
rexp = r"(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})"

def make_repl(match_obj):
    # Get the first group and convert to int
    month_num = int(match_obj.group(1)) 
    # Get month name from lookup
    month_name = month_num_dict[month_num] 
    # Format month name and other groups into the replacement string
    return f"{month_name} {match_obj.group(2)}, {match_obj.group(3)}" 

item_mod = re.sub(rexp, make_repl, item)
print(item_mod)
```

which gives us what we need:

```
May 25, 1999
```

Answer (score 1):

The way humans do datetime is [ridiculous](https://xkcd.com/927/) so confusion is understandable (IMO).

I also hope you don't mind that I did not use regex here, as python can do this on its own.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str_in = "04-03-2002"

datetime_in = datetime.strptime(datetime_str_in, "%m-%d-%Y")
datetime_out = datetime_in.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

print(datetime_in)
print(datetime_out)
```

Output:

```
2002-04-03 00:00:00
April 03, 2002
```

It is also possible to do this (effectively) in one line, though arguably at the expense of a little readability.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = "04-03-2002"

datetime_out = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%m-%d-%Y").strftime("%B %d, %Y")

print(datetime_out)
```

If we have the following sample CSV;

```
Date,Metric
02-03-2002,1
05-04-2003,2
06-07-2004,3
```

A full Pythonic solution could be as follows.

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

in_file = "datetest.csv"
out_file = "out.csv"

out_row = ["Date", "Metric"]

with open(out_file, "w", newline="") as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    with open(in_file, "r", newline="") as csv_in:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
        print(reader)
        writer.writerow(out_row)
        out_row = []
        for row in enumerate(reader):
            datetime_out = ""
            if row[0] == 0:
                pass
            else:
                for item in row[1]:
                    try:
                        datetime_out = datetime.strptime(item, "%m-%d-%Y").strftime("%B %d, %Y")
                        out_row.append(datetime_out)

                    except TypeError:
                        print("Type error")
                        out_row.append(item)

                    except ValueError:
                        print("Value error")
                        out_row.append(item)
            if out_row:
                writer.writerow(out_row)
```

As mentioned in my comment, I would strongly suggest [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) for clarity.